# Jmeter - regular expression to extract value

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am somewhat new to regular expressions.I am trying to capture a value using a regular expression extractor that appears to be encapsulated in '\'. Since \ and " are special character in Perl, how would I extract this value?

The value comes out of the HTML like this:

> state_hiddenfld_value=\"504634900\"

I already have an extractor that works for the name; do I need to include that as well?

I have tried this extractor:

Regular Expression: state_hiddenfld_value="\"(.+?)\"
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default Value:VSTABLEID_NOT_FOUND

I'm not sure if I need something else in my regular expression.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

we can use the following regular Expression

```
state_hiddenfld_value=\\"(.+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression should be

```
state_hiddenfld_value=\\"(.+?)\\"
```